# scalaxb generate XML element with attributes

Tags: scala, scalaxb

scalaxb has generated the following case class definition based on my XSD:

```
case class Identifier(
   value: String,
   attributes: Map[String, scalaxb.DataRecord[Any]] = Map()) {
   lazy val typeValue = attributes("@type").as[String]
 }
```

I'm struggling with how to instance this case class (especially how to add to its attributes).  Tried the below option

```
Identifier("name", Map("@attribute" -> scalaxb.DataRecord("attributeStringVal"))
```

When i tried to create a Map and pass it on to Identifier object, I am getting the below error while compiling the scala code

"could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scalaxb.CanWriteXML[String]".

Anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error. In order to implicit `scalaxb.CanWriteXML[String]` to be available, you need to import the `scalaxbPackageName`. It can be found in `xmlProtocol.scala` trait. Assuming scalaxbPackageName is `com.package.subpackage` then you need to `import com.package.subpackage._`